# String / Bytes issue when upgrading from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code, python-imaging-library

I try to generate base64 img of QRCode using Python 3 this way:

```
def gen_qrcode(data):
    import base64
    import io
    import qrcode

    qrc = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,
                        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_Q,
                        box_size=8,
                        border=4)
    qrc.add_data(data)
    qrc.make(fit=True)
    img = qrc.make_image()

    output = io.StringIO()
    img.save(output, 'PNG') # This line is now a problem with Python 3
    output.seek(0)
    output_s = output.read()
    b64 = base64.b64encode(output_s)
    img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(b64)

    return img_tag
```

It worked well with Python 2 (the only changed code is StringIO replaced by IO) but now I have an error:

```
TypeError at /qrcode
string argument expected, got 'bytes'
-> img.save(output, 'PNG')
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
output = io.BytesIO
```

This will expect bytes and produce bytes for input to base64.b64encode.

To remove the leading "b" from the resulting output `.decode()` has to be used as mentioned in the comments:

```
b64 = base64.b64encode(output_s).decode()
```

Comment: This should work in both 2.7 and 3.x.  I believe the rest of your code is version independent also.

Comment: This solves the first error thanks, but the output is `b'the-b64-string'` instead of `'the-b64-string'`. This created an invalid URL.